# DCT taking too long to be implemented

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dct

I am trying to implement DCT 2-D but as mentioned it takes too long. I have tried it on Matlab using dct2d and it is really a LOT faster. I am using dct-2D from wikipedia page:
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform
  Any ideas?

Comment: ok why the - (minus)??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an algorithm that factors the DCT matrix. If you do it as a straight matrix multiplication, it will be sloooooooow.

Also, you might want to use scaled integers rather than floating point.